# NullPointerException Error when i read from a text

Tags: java, processing

I get an error on:

```
line = node_reader.readLine();
```

When the text file is empty I get a `NullPointerException` error. If there is data on the text I do not get the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
void file_open () {

    String line = "test";
    BufferedReader node_reader;
    node_reader = createReader("nodedata.txt");

    while (line !=null ) {   

        try {

            line = node_reader.readLine();

            if ( line != null ) {
                String[] pieces = split(line, TAB);
                int a = int(pieces[0]);
                int b = int(pieces[1]);
                int c = int(pieces[2]);
                int d = int(pieces[3]);
                int e = int(pieces[4]);

                listofNodes.add(new Node(a, b, e));  //
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            line = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the text file:

```
138 102 100 36  0
95  293 100 36  1
```

Comment: Where does the NullPointerException occurs?

Comment: on: line = node_reader.readLine();

Comment: That doesn't look like valid code to me... `int(pieces[0])`? Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is just about the perfect example of how *not* to ask a question.

Comment: @baris22 First bug must be at `createReader( "nodedata.txt" );` This method is returning a `null`. And hence is the `NPE` at the specified line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in

```
node_reader = createReader("nodedata.txt");
```

Inside this method, the file is probably not opened correctly.  Go to this method and validate that the method correctly creates a BufferedReader.

Answer (score 0):

How do you create BufferReader? Try:

```
BufferedReader node_reader
   = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("nodedata.txt"));
```

Comment: In Processing you can't use `FileReader`, the IDE instead give to you `createReader()` and returns a BufferedReader...
I can't tell you why they made this decision!

To use it you have to import `java.io.FileReader`